# Resarting AppEngine after a file is modified

Tags: google-app-engine, dev-appserver

Whenever I make a change to my html file, I have to resart appengine server to see the change reflected. Why is this so? In Flask for example the server automatically reloads whenever it detects a file change. Can this be done in AppEngine?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the normal behavior for local development. You should be able to update your html files, as your code, without the need to restart the server.

Can you tell us more about your setup? Might there be a caching mechanism in your code that doesn't check the filesystem to refresh appropriately?